# Create depth stream on Tree structure

Tags: java, tree, java-8, java-stream

So, I have a basic tree structure consisting of tree nodes linking to other tree nodes with parent and children references. I want to create a method that returns a Stream that streams either from a leaf node to root node or root to leaf. I have implemented this already but I'm looking for a solution where the minimal amount of objects are created. Preferably none. Here is my code:

```
  public class TreeNode<TNode> {

      private TNode iValue;

      private TreeNode<TNode> iParentNode = null;

      private List<TreeNode<TNode>> iChildren = new ArrayList<>();

      public TreeNode(TNode value) {
          this(value, null);
      }

      private TreeNode(TNode value, TreeNode<TNode> parentNode) {
          iValue = value;
          iParentNode = parentNode;
      }

      public Stream<TreeNode<TNode>> streamFromLeaf() {
          return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new LeafFirstIterator(this), Spliterator.SIZED),
            false);
      }

      public Stream<TreeNode<TNode>> streamFromRoot() {
          return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new RootFirstIterator(this), Spliterator.SIZED),
            false);
      }

      public TNode getValue() {
          return iValue;
      }

      public TreeNode<TNode> getParent() {
          return iParentNode;
      }

      public TreeNode<TNode> addChild(TNode childValue) {
          TreeNode<TNode> childNode = new TreeNode<TNode>(childValue, iNodeNameFunction, this);
          iChildren.add(childNode);
          return childNode;
      }

      public boolean isLeaf() {
          return iChildren.size() == 0;
      }

      public boolean isRoot() {
          return iParentNode == null;
      }

      public List<TreeNode<TNode>> getChildren() {
          return iChildren;
      }

      class LeafFirstIterator implements Iterator<TreeNode<TNode>> {

          private TreeNode<TNode> iNextNode;

          LeafFirstIterator(TreeNode<TNode> leafNode) {
              iNextNode = leafNode;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean hasNext() {
              return iNextNode != null;
          }

          @Override
          public TreeNode<TNode> next() {
              TreeNode<TNode> current = iNextNode;
              iNextNode = current.getParent();
              return current;
          }

      }

      class RootFirstIterator implements Iterator<TreeNode<TNode>> {

          private List<TreeNode<TNode>> iNodes = new ArrayList<>();

          private int iNextIndex;

          RootFirstIterator(TreeNode<TNode> leafNode) {
              TreeNode<TNode> currentNode = leafNode;
              while (currentNode != null) {
                  iNodes.add(currentNode);
                  currentNode = currentNode.getParent();
              }
              iNextIndex = iNodes.size() - 1;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean hasNext() {
               return iNextIndex >= 0;
           }

           @Override
           public TreeNode<TNode> next() {
               return iNodes.get(iNextIndex--);
           }

       }
   }
```

This works fine but my "problem" is, a lot of objects are create for each stream call.

- StreamSupport.stream creates new ReferencePipeline
- Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize creates new IteratorSpliterator
- I create my own Iterator implementation to pass to Spliterator
- RootFirstIterator creates new ArrayList

The streams are going to be used heavily so I want do avoid object creation as much as possible. Iterating the tree structure without streams is a simple matter. Right now I'm only using the map method of stream. I could just have a method that takes a Consumer, iterate the depth and call the consumer for each node, and no objects would be created, but I would loose all stream functionality. That would look something like this:

```
public void iterateUp(Consumer<TreeNode<TNode>> consumer) {
    doIterateUp(this, consumer);
}

public static <T> void doIterateUp(TreeNode<T> node, Consumer<TreeNode<T>> consumer) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    consumer.accept(node);
    doIterateUp(node.getParent(), consumer);
}
```

and iterating down from root would be just as simple.

Any ideas on this? Am I going about this the wrong way? Should TreeNode implement or extend some interface/class instead? Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a stream. Use your alternative, which has a name: the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Streams aren't always the right approach, and this is a classic case for using the visitor pattern.

If you absolutely must have a stream, have your consumer either collect the nodes in a List then stream that, or wire up the consumer to the `next()` method of an Iterator (with some code to make it behave properly) and use StreamSupport to turn it into a stream.

Comment: It's not a must but would be really nice. My other thought was to pass a filter predicate, a map function, and a consumer to the iterate methods and I would get partial stream-like func and no objects would be created. But it seems a little ugly to me. Collecting nodes to a list and streaming that would be I think quite similar object creation wise to my solution, maybe a little better actually.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t share your performance concerns, however, there is room for simplification of your code which might address some of your concerns as a side-effect.

You made the common mistake of starting with an `Iterator` implementation, much likely because the `Iterator` interface old and well known. But implementing it is cumbersome and the fact that you don’t need to wrap an `Iterator` in a `Spliterator` if you just implement `Spliterator` directly, is only a neat side effect:

```
public Stream<TreeNode<TNode>> streamFromLeaf() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new LeafFirstSpliterator<>(this), false);
}
static class LeafFirstSpliterator<TNode>
extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<TreeNode<TNode>> {
    private TreeNode<TNode> iNextNode;
    LeafFirstSpliterator(TreeNode<TNode> leafNode) {
        super(100, ORDERED|NONNULL);
        iNextNode = leafNode;
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super TreeNode<TNode>> action) {
        if(iNextNode==null) return false;
        action.accept(iNextNode);
        iNextNode=iNextNode.getParent();
        return true;
    }
}
```

To me, the `Spliterator` implementation looks much cleaner, at least it’s nothing to be afraid of, and it might allow a faster stream traversal. You might consider overriding the `forEachRemaining` method as well as it’s straight-forward to implement.

For the stream from root to leaf, a temporary storage seems to be unavoidable, but if it is, don’t waste time with low level coding at all, just use the storage’s built-in streaming capability:

```
public Stream<TreeNode<TNode>> streamFromRoot() {
    ArrayDeque<TreeNode<TNode>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for(TreeNode<TNode> n = this; n != null; n = n.getParent())
        deque.addFirst(n);
    return deque.stream();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Good pointers. As you stated, there is a tendency to resort to iterators since it's more familiar. The Spliterator approach does look cleaner. Will try it out and have a harder look at the new java 8 stuff. Regarding performance. The code is latency critical and we try not to drive GC to much in order to avoid latency outliers.